# While running HLK in printer driver devmode corruptor test in that Run DevmodeCorruptW.exe case failing as mentioned below logs?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

Cause : Task "Run DevModeCorruptW.exe" is Marked Failed From the LogFile

Cause : Copying File "C:\hlk\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRun8B59CC52-FC5E-EE11-80CC-D43D7E64875C\DevModeCorruptW.wtl" Fails

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\hlk\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRun8B59CC52-FC5E-EE11-80CC-D43D7E64875C\DevModeCorruptW.wtl"

Cause : Copying File "C:\hlk\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRun8B59CC52-FC5E-EE11-80CC-D43D7E64875C\DevModeCorruptW.wtl" Fails

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\hlk\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRun8B59CC52-FC5E-EE11-80CC-D43D7E64875C\DevModeCorruptW.wtl"

Cause : Task is Marked Failed as all the Counts are Zero in the LogFile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g17TU.png)

expecting that Run DevmodecorruptW.exe test should pass..